# how can i add a property to 'this' object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Now something about make me confused again. In the file, i see the following code`this.xCenter = options.xPos;` however, i can not find the place define `xCenter` in `this` object. And then  i add a line like `this.myattr = 12;`, to my surprise, the code run normally and did not show any error. before i know the running result, i think the code should be running unsucessfully because `this` did not define the property of `myattr`, so i'm confused. That's really different from syntax of Java. In turn, i think it's a way define/add a perperty for an object, is my assumption right, or just the code means something else, guys?

Comment: "That's really difference from syntax of Java" - Correct: Javascript and Java are two distinct languages and what is true in one is often not so in the other. Ignore the name "Javascript" - there is no real relationship with Java.

Comment: BTW jQuery is a Javascript library that has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamically (and weakly) typed language. You can add properties as and when you want. They do not need to be declared first.

For example :

```
var obj = {};      // create an object but we don't define any properties
obj.foo = "hello"; // property foo just got created
obj.bar = 10;      // and same for bar
console.log(obj);
```

Java on the other hand is a statically (and strongly) typed language, thus variables and properties have to be declared before being used.